# navigator.serviceWorker Property 'sync' does not exist on type 'ServiceWorkerRegistration'

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I have an Angular 14.1.1 app configured for Progressive Web Apps. I'm getting an error Property 'sync' does not exist on type 'ServiceWorkerRegistration' when using the following code.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
    if (registration.sync) { //Error: Property 'sync' does not exist on type 'ServiceWorkerRegistration'.
        // Background Sync is supported.
    } else {
        // Background Sync isn't supported.
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the question? The error states that the property `sync` is not declared in the type of `ServiceWorkerRegistration`

Answer (score 2):

Since [background-sync is currently a draft](https://wicg.github.io/background-sync/spec/), the typings aren't backed into typescript yet.

You'll have to create your own definitions:

```
interface SyncManager {
  getTags(): Promise<string[]>;
  register(tag: string): Promise<void>;
}

declare global {
  interface ServiceWorkerRegistration {
    readonly sync: SyncManager;
  }

  interface SyncEvent extends ExtendableEvent {
    readonly lastChance: boolean;
    readonly tag: string;
  }

  interface ServiceWorkerGlobalScopeEventMap {
    sync: SyncEvent;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Kestal did it work for you ?